# Phpstorm 7 reload in browser / live edit - how to use it with php files

Tags: phpstorm, liveedit

I've done the tutorials on how to setup **Phpstorm** to use live edit, and I started using the "**Reload in browser**" functionality, but in version **7** it reloads only that single url which i've  set up at in the Debug configuration.

My problem is that before, in version 6 as I remeber, it automatically reloaded every single page that was opened in the browser, and was related to the domain I had in Debug configuration URL. (So if I had www.mysite.local set up in **PHP Web aplication debug configuration**, it also reloaded www.mysite.local/something, www.mysite.local/backoffice..), but not anymore in v7.

Does anybody know if it is still possible in the new version, so I don't have to make a configuration for every single page?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now creating confifuration for each page seems to be necessary. Please vote for [WEB-10165](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10165)